# Кракозябры в мобильной версии на IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина:
В мобильной версии в полях формы отображаются кракозябры, причем только на устройствах Apple. В Web  все в порядке.
[image: скрин]

Comment: `<meta charset="utf-8">` ?

Comment: вот как по такому вопросу можно что-то понять? автор, на какой ответ ты ожидаешь?